# Simple custom function in Excel, using Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have a faster process looking up cross references.

Right now I use `VLOOKUP`, and it works fine - but it takes time when it needs to be done multiple times everyday.

It is always the same sheet I use to lookup the cross references, so the only thing that changes is my input value in the `VLOOKUP` function.

Therefore I want a function where I only input 1 value to get the `VLOOKUP` value.

The idea is a function like:

```
=CROSS(ID)
```

where

```
CROSS = vlookup(ID, table_array, col_index_num,[range_lookup])
```

So the `vlookup_value` is replaced by `ID`.

I hope you can provide me with some answers - thanks in advance.

I have tried multiple different things, but with no success.
As I am new, I've googled and recorded macros to look for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a UDF (user defined function) for that, using the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup):

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CROSS(ID As Variant) As Variant

    CROSS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)

End Function
```

Comment: Cool - but i cannot make it work. I believe it is because i am so new to VBA.

Comment: I get a syntax error in the 'public function' line. 
i have changed :
CROSS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)

to:
CROSS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID,C[5]:C[6],2,0)

Comment: you must provide a range object as `table_array` like `Worksheets("mysheet").Range("E:F")`.

Comment: Ok -  is that like:

    Dim table_array As Range
    table_array.Range ("E:F")

Because i just did this for all the variables, but it returns with an 'invalid use of property'-error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as it should now!

The code ended up like this:

```
Sub crossref()

Option Explicit

Public Function CROSS(ID As Variant) As Variant
CROSS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID, Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E:F"), 2, 0)

End Function
```